# C++ finding num of elements in a char* array

Tags: c++, arrays

is there a way to know num of elements in a char* array?

my code is :

```
char* inputOptions[]={
    NULL,     
    "first sentence",
    "second sentence"}

for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
   cout<<inputOptions[j]<<endl;
```

and I would like to change '3' to some expression that depends on 'arr'. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const char * inputOptions[] = {
    NULL,     
    "first sentence",
    "second sentence" };

const int numOptions = sizeof(inputOptions) / sizeof(inputOptions[0]);
```

Comment: Because dynamic arrays are just pointers - the compiler can not know at compile-time how much memory will be allocated to a pointer at run-time.

Comment: The denominator should be `sizeof(inputOptions[0])` rather than hard-coded for `char*`. Doing it that way costs nothing, and makes the code more robust against type changes.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can write

```
std::distance(std::begin(inputOptions), std::end(inputOptions));
```

In C++03, use

```
sizeof inputOptions / sizeof inputOptions[0]
```

However, in C++11 you would do better to access the array using range for:

```
for (auto option: inputOptions)
   cout << option << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sizeof()` with static arrays, it will give you the size in bytes. If you divide that by the pointer size, you will get the size of the array:

```
siz = sizeof(inputOptions)/sizeof(char*);
```